# UPBGE - Camera Background Image

Tags: game-engine, camera, image

I'm trying to run the game with a camera background image, like pre-rendered background games (Final Fantasy, Resident Evil...) When I run "embedded start" it works, the camera background image appears, but it doesn't appear when I run "standalone start". Do you know which is the best way to do this? Thanks so much.

Miguel

Comment: As it stands, it is kind of difficult for us to understand what your problem is in order to help you.  Please add some details about what exactly you are doing and what "it works/doesn't work" indicates.

Comment: in my opinion: it is pretty clear what he wants. @Miguel: did you ever try it with a HDRI?

Comment: Sorry guys I don't know why I didn't receive notification of your responses. I abandoned the project. If I take it back and get any progress I will post it here.